# Compass font-face mixin bold

Tags: css, font-face, sass, compass-sass

I am using the @font-face mixin with Compass (0.11.beta.1) and having trouble defining my bold and italic fonts.

I can successfully load and use fonts with the following code:

```
@include font-face("PTSerif", font-files("/path/to/font/PTF55F_W.ttf", truetype), "/path/to/font/PTF55F_W.eot");
```

However I can't find a way to define the bold font-face. The source says that the style argument has been deprecated, and trying to use it has no effect on the output .css file.

```
@mixin font-face($name, $font-files, $eot: false, $postscript: false, $style: false) {
  @if $postscript or $style {
    @warn "The $postscript and $style variables have been deprecated in favor of the Paul Irish smiley bulletproof technique."; }
  @font-face {
    font-family: quote($name);
    @if $eot {
  src: font-url($eot); }
    src: local("☺"), $font-files; } }
```

I currently have two alternatives:

1. Edit the .css files afterwards. No good for maintainability
2. Define different fonts for the different styles (also not ideal, but currently the mos workable) e.g.

   @include font-face("PTSerif")
   @include font-face("PTSerif-B")

Haven't been able to find any examples of how to do this properly- being able to use font-weight:bold;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acarabott, I've made a commit to compass for this some time ago, and it seems to ship with 0.12.alpha.

Notice the $weight and $style parameters here:
http://beta.compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/font_face/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of combining regular, bold and italic that I have working just fine: [@font-face :: IM FELL ENGLISH](http://www.iandevlin.com/font-face/).

Comment: I was specifically asking about using Compass to do this, it seems your css is hand coded?
Also, you have achieved this with presentational classes, which I wanted to avoid.